# when converting power to number the number formatting is not good

Tags: java, android

I have got some troubles with conversion, but the following code converts right sometime and sometime wrong

```
        double d = Double.parseDouble(results.get(position)); // Also accepts format like "1.574e10"
        Log.e("test",String.valueOf(d));
        String s1=  String.format("%f",d);
        Log.e("test",s1);
```

This is example for conversion didn't work

```
08-28 12:15:53.679: E/test(22754): 1.4910315055357396E-9
08-28 12:15:53.679: E/test(22754): 0,000000
```

Comment: `%d` is integer converter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your double is very small and %f prints only **6** numbers after the decimal point by default.

Instead use:

```
String s1 = String.format("%.10f", d);
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to format a double to a string would be:

```
String.format("%1$,.4f", myDouble)
```

The above example gives you an accuracy of 4 decimal places. Another way to format a double would be with DecimalFormat:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
String number = df.format(543.235555);
```

Comment: problem is i need this number like thet 0.000000001.. :) not in that

Comment: Try the first one but with "%1$,.20f"